# Why is the function triggered on the entire layout and not only on the image?

Tags: python, kivy, touch

I want the function on_touch_down() in the class myField() to be called only by clicking on the image, but not on the whole screen. What do I have to change to achieve this?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class MyField(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = "image1.jpg"
        self.size_hint = 0.1,0.1

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print("touch down")


class MyLayout(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(MyField())


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_touch_down` method belongs to Kivy's `Widget` and you shouldn't prevent its execution.
What you could do though, is to modify your own version of it, to suit your needs, like that:

```py
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("touch down")
```

With this, you only print something if the click is inside the boundaries of your image.